# Groups - Compositions

Tags: group-theory, functions, notation

If the f is written to the right of its argument does that mean the composition of $f g$ is actually $g(f(x))$ instead of being $f(g(x))$ which is the notation I'm used to.

I ask this because I read in group theory writing the f to the right of its argument is the convention.

Comment: $f g$ is the map that takes $x$ to $(x^f)^g$ or $((x)f)g$ depending on whether you use exponential notation like for permutation groups or multiplicative notation like you use for matrix groups.

Comment: Unfortunately both notations ($fg$ and $gf$) are in common use. You will have to rely on the particular author's usage. $f\circ g$ is unambiguous. I find the "right hand side" application unnatural, but many others don't. It often goes hand in hand with putting the function to the right of the argument as well ($xf$ for the more customary $f(x)$--yikes!).